# Logs creation for Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: logging, installation, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am trying to create a installer for my application using the VS setup project. Now I want that in the event of any failure I should be able to track what went wrong with the help of a log file.

So my question is,  how do i get a hook into the various event (e.g path select, disclaimer agreed to , etc ) so that I can log them. Currently the only place that i can plug my code in is with the custom actions but things can go wrong even before that.

Any suggestion on how to deal with this is highly appreciated.

Thanks, Oyshik

Answer (score 0):

We can generate the logs for the MSI run by setting the registry key option. Please follow this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300#fixit4me) to solve the issue. After following the steps mentioned in the link, you can find the logs in **%temp%** folder with extension ***.log**

You have to edit the following registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer

Set the value of the key "**Logging**"
Value: "**voicewarmupx**"

The value is nothing but the combination of options to log as described below,

v - Verbose output
o - Out-of-disk-space messages
i - Status messages
c - Initial UI parameters
e - All error messages
w - Non-fatal warnings
a - Start up of actions
r - Action-specific records
m - Out-of-memory or fatal exit information
u - User requests
p - Terminal properties
+ - Append to existing file
! - Flush each line to the log
x - Extra debugging information. The "x" flag is available only on Windows Server 2003 and later operating systems, and on the MSI redistributable version 3.0, and on later versions of the MSI redistributable.